# ufw allow access to mongo only from my IP address (IPv6)

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ufw

I want to allow connections to an instance of mongo only from a specific IPv6 address. I'm using `ufw` as my firewall, but a simple

```
ufw allow from __IPv6_address__ to any port __mongo_port__
```

Doesn't produce a connection from that other address. Only local connections work. What's missing here?

Answer (score 2):

take a look at [bindIp option](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp) in /etc/mongod.conf file. it might be that it's binds mongod to listen only local loopback `127.0.0.1` but not ip-address of `eth0`